# gmail api Send Mail not working C# Console Application (Insufficient Authentication Scopes)

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-platform, gmail-api

I am new to google cloud / gmail API. In c# I would like to use their gmail api to:

1. logon to google cloud - works
2. read List items - works
3. **send email** - does not work

The Api in step 3 Returns **Insufficient Request Scopes (403)** I feel confident I am logged on to my cloud account: The line of code i suspect most is this:

```
 static string[] Scopes = { GmailService.Scope.GmailAddonsCurrentActionCompose, GmailService.Scope.GmailAddonsCurrentMessageAction };
```

I am getting this error

```
 Request had insufficient authentication scopes. [403]
Errors [
        Message[Insufficient Permission] Location[ - ] Reason[insufficientPermissions] Domain[global]
]
```

// Code

```
 class Program
{
    // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
    // at ~/.credentials/gmail-dotnet-quickstart.json
    static string[] Scopes = { GmailService.Scope.GmailAddonsCurrentActionCompose, GmailService.Scope.GmailAddonsCurrentMessageAction };
    static string ApplicationName = "Gmail API .NET Quickstart";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UserCredential credential;
        using (var stream =
            new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is created
            // automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time.
            string credPath = "token.json";
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
        }
        // Create Gmail API service.
        var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });
        // Define parameters of request.
        UsersResource.LabelsResource.ListRequest request = service.Users.Labels.List("me");
        // List labels.
        IList<Label> labels = request.Execute().Labels;
        Console.WriteLine("Labels:");
        if (labels != null && labels.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var labelItem in labels)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", labelItem.Name);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No labels found.");
        }
        string plainText = "Body Test";
        var newMsg = new Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message();
        newMsg.Raw = Program.Base64UrlEncode(plainText.ToString());
        try
        {
            service.Users.Messages.Send(newMsg, "me").Execute();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        /*
         {"Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError\r\nRequest had insufficient authentication scopes. 
          [403]\r\nErrors [\r\n\tMessage[Insufficient Permission] Location[ - ] Reason[insufficientPermissions] Domain[global]\r\n]\r\n"}   Google.GoogleApiException
         */
        Console.Read();
    }
    public static string Base64UrlEncode(string input)
    {
        var inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(inputBytes).Replace("+", "-").Replace("/", "_").Replace("=", "");
    }
}
```

//Output from above

```
Credential file saved to: token.json
Labels:
CHAT
SENT
INBOX
IMPORTANT
TRASH
DRAFT
SPAM
CATEGORY_FORUMS
CATEGORY_UPDATES
CATEGORY_PERSONAL
CATEGORY_PROMOTIONS
CATEGORY_SOCIAL
STARRED
UNREAD
Sent Messages
Pa0
P
Insurance
Junk E-mail
Licenses
Notes
Personal
Receipts
Travel
Work
Tickets
**Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Request had insufficient authentication scopes. [403]
Errors [
        Message[Insufficient Permission] Location[ - ] Reason[insufficientPermissions] Domain[global]
]**
```

Comment: i am making some progress. This code is based on the QuickStart. I needed to modify the cloud id itself using the Cloud console to allow sending of mail. Now I am getting the next error... I will update this issue with results when i eventually win

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay:
I decided to take the credentials file provided by GMAIL.API and put into a single line Environment Variable and Do a JSON Convert to a GoogleClientSecrets:

```
    private static GoogleClientSecrets GetSecretsFromEnvironment()
    {
        var environmentConfiguration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();   
        var secretsEnv = environmentConfiguration["GoogleSecrets"];
        var secrets = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GoogleClientSecrets>(secretsEnv);
        return secrets;
    }
```

the appsettings.json

```
{
  "MailSettings": {
    "account": "mark.d.wardell@gmail.com",
    "subject": "Please Confirm Account",
    "from": "mark.d.wardell@gmail.com",
    "HTML": "<b>Hello {0}</b>"
  }
}
```

credentials.json as provided by google cloud console. I made into a single line string and added to EnvironmentVariable

[image]
And the calling code:

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace SendMail
{
    class Program
    {
        // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
        // at ~/.credentials/gmail-dotnet-quickstart.json
        static string[] Scopes = { GmailService.Scope.GmailAddonsCurrentActionCompose, GmailService.Scope.GmailAddonsCurrentMessageAction, GmailService.Scope.GmailSend };
        static string ApplicationName = "Restful Resting Place";
        static async Task Main(params string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                    .Build();
                Dictionary<string, string> MailSettings;
                MailSettings = configuration.GetSection("MailSettings").GetChildren().ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
                MailSettings.Add("to", args[0]);
                MailSettings.Add("link", args[1]);
                GoogleClientSecrets gSecrets = GetSecretsFromEnvironment();
                string credPath = "token.json";
                UserCredential gcredential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                       gSecrets.Secrets,
                       Scopes,
                       MailSettings["account"],
                       CancellationToken.None,
                       new FileDataStore(credPath, true));
                var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = gcredential,
                    ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
                });

                SendItTwo(service, MailSettings);
                Console.WriteLine()
            }catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }   
        }
        private static GoogleClientSecrets GetSecretsFromEnvironment()
        {
            var environmentConfiguration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();   
            var secretsEnv = environmentConfiguration["GoogleSecrets"];
            var secrets = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GoogleClientSecrets>(secretsEnv);
            return secrets;
        }
        public static void SendItTwo(GmailService gmail,   Dictionary<string,string> dict)
        {
            MailMessage mailmsg = new MailMessage();
            {
                mailmsg.Subject = dict["subject"];
                mailmsg.Body = string.Format(dict["HTML"],dict["link"]);
                mailmsg.From = new MailAddress(dict["from"]);
                mailmsg.To.Add(new MailAddress(dict["to"]));         
                mailmsg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            }

            ////add attachment if specified
            if (dict.ContainsKey("attachement"))
            {
                if (File.Exists(dict["attachment"]))
                {
                    Attachment data = new Attachment(dict["attachment"]);
                    mailmsg.Attachments.Add(data);

                }else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: Invalid Attachemnt");
                }
            }     
            //Make mail message a Mime message
            MimeKit.MimeMessage mimemessage = MimeKit.MimeMessage.CreateFromMailMessage(mailmsg);
            Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message finalmessage = new Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message();
            finalmessage.Raw = Base64UrlEncode(mimemessage.ToString());  
            var result = gmail.Users.Messages.Send(finalmessage, "me").Execute();
        } 
        public static string Base64UrlEncode(string input)
        {
            var inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(inputBytes).Replace("+", "-").Replace("/", "_").Replace("=", "");
        }
    }
}
```